# Javascript execution in dynamically loaded dialogs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have som problems regarding getting javascript to fire correctly inside dialog.

Below is the code from my scripts.js wich i currently use to load a dialog

```
function LoadDialog(url, title) {
    var DialogBox = $('<div class="dialog-container"></div>').dialog({ modal: true, autoOpen: false, resizeable: true }).dialog({ width: 500, height: 'auto' });
    DialogBox.html('<div class="ajax-load"><img src="/Content/loading.gif" alt="loading"></div>').dialog({ buttons: null, title: 'Loading..' });
    DialogBox.dialog('open').load(url, function () {
        DialogBox.dialog({ title: title, Buttons: null, position: 'center', close: function (ev, ui) { $(this).dialog("destroy"); } });
    });
}

$(function () {
    $('.as-dialog').click(function (e) { LoadDialog($(this).attr('href'), $(this).attr('title')); return false; });
});
```

Though no javascript code fires by default inside the dialog. For example i load a small form with unobtrusive validation into the dialog. No body, head etc, only a container div and the form itself. By default validation dont work and if i add event handlers for the form under script.js $(function(){}) it dont fire. If i add the following js references and codeblock to be loaded with the form it works with one problem:

```
<script src="/Scripts/libs/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/Scripts/libs/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#form_Create').submit(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

The non functioning regarding the code above is that validation will always work but if i open the dialog, close it, then open it again, the preventdefault will stop working and the form will post. Could this perhaps be a multiple load of script issue or something? Though since no 'doc ready' code works in dialog if placed in scripts.js (standard javascript functions work though) i dont really have another option. 
Is there a better way to work with javascript inside dynamically loaded files or do i have to place the entire forms in the parent page to be able to work against them reliably? 
Any input on how you should handle this?

Comment: Any chance you can provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ for this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below method to open the dialog seems to have solved my primary problem:

```
var Box = $('#dialog-container');
    if (Box.length === 0) {
        Box = $('<div id="dialog-container"></div>').appendTo('body');
    } else { Box.empty(); }
```

Unsure atm if the empty() is needed because it seems that load does this anyway. But with this code i can open the dialogs how many times i like and the codeblock will still execute.

Though my issue / question regarding if i have to live with calling some script files from the loaded pages or there is a better way of enabling scriptrunning from the parental loaded files. But atleast everything seems to work well now.

Comment: After further testing i realized that $(this).dialog("destroy"); removed everything in #dialog-container, it did not remove the root element. Adding a remove statement on the div at close also solved the reopening issue.

Answer (score 0):

A fiddle would indeed be welcome, but for a kick-off:

```
DialogBox.dialog({ title: title, Buttons: null, position: 'center', close: function (ev, ui) { $(this).dialog("destroy"); } });
```

This line could be an issue, if we apply some formatting, and break it up:

```
var obj = {};
obj.title = title;
obj.Buttons = null;
obj.position = 'center';
obj.close = function(ev,ui)
{
    $(this).dialog("destroy");//-->this will point to obj!!
};
DialogBox.dialog(obj);
```

I think what you want is for `this` to point to, what is commonly referred to as either `that` or `_self`.

Or, what you could do is create a closure, to preserve a reference to the context in which the object was created:

```
obj.close = (function(that)
{
    return function(ev,ui)
    {
        that.dialog("destroy");
    };
})($(this));
```

Maybe this is irrelevant to what your problem is, but just to be on the safe side: set up a fiddle

Comment: Sorry for the delay in respons, some urgent work came in between this. Anyway i modified LoadDialog to: 
´var Box = $('<div class="dialog-container"></div>');
    var Opts = {};
    Opts.title = title;
    Opts.Buttons = null;
    Opts.position = 'center';
    Opts.modal = true;
    Opts.autoOpen = false;
    Opts.close = (function (that) { return function (ev, ui) { that.dialog("destroy"); }; })($(this));
    Box.dialog(Opts).load(url, function () { }).dialog('open');´

Comment: Seems i took too long editing the above post(why that would be limited i dont know). Anyway: The aboveworks exactly as before unfortunately. I checked in fiddler earlier and chrome devtools to make sure no js error occours wich it dont. It just dont seem to load the scriptblock part. This is the basic fiddler log: http://postimage.org/image/kulrpi1o5/ I can check any requested details. Havent tried putting my scriptblock in a js file but i dont really see why that would make any difference.

Comment: Best of all worlds would be to get the dialog to actually consume the js loaded from the parent page. But that doesnt seem to work for $(function(){}) bound code at all when using load.

Comment: Added the full session here: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=335DA8E85CE9A00B!172&authkey=!ALZIoVOjLCi2EaE

Comment: To explain the log: /LoginAjax is what the dialog posts to via $.post, /Login is what the form posts to if the codeblock dont fire.